# Mock an external library object for testing in go

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am trying to do unit testing on a golang HTTP function that does a post.  To do that without actually posting to an API, I want to mock the `Post()` method from `*http.Client` object from the `net/http` package.  The challenge is that to my knowledge I cannot create a Mock object and stick it onto an external library object, I am wondering if this is possible.  Here is my test:

http_test.go

```golang
type (
    MockPost struct {
        mock.Mock
    }
)

func (m *MockPost) Post(url string, contentType string, body io.Reader) (resp *http.Response, err error) {
    args := m.Called(url, contentType, body)
    return nil, args.Error(0)
}

func TestFunc(t *testing.T) {
    mockPost := &MockPost{}
    mockPost.On("Post", "apistring", nil, mock.Anything).Return(nil)

    err := functionNeedsTesting("apistring", nil, *mockPost) // <- cannot use mockPost bc expected *http.Client yada yada...
    if err != nil {
        t.Error(err)
        t.FailNow()
    }
    mockPost.AssertExpectations(t)
}
```

here is the simplified function that I want to test, here `client` uses `*http.Client`, can I mock this?

http.go

```golang
func makePost(apiString string, body []byte, client *http.Client) error {
    resp, err := client.Post(apiString, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(body))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != 201 { // created response code
        bodyBytes, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return fmt.Errorf("%s", bodyBytes)
    }
    return nil
}
```

here is the exact error:

```
cannot use *mockPost (variable of type MockPost) as *http.Client value in argument to makePost
```

Comment: Alternative: record and replay http requests: https://github.com/dnaeon/go-vcr

Comment: "without actually posting to an API, I want to mock the Post() method from *http.Client" No you don't. You want to make an actual HTTP call to a fake you provide via net/http/httptest.Server.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd want to do is have `makePost` take an interface, instead of an `http.Client`:

```
type HttpPoster interface {
    Post(url, contentType string, body io.Reader) (resp *http.Response, err error)
}

func makePost(apiString string, body []byte, client HttpPoster) error {
    resp, err := client.Post(apiString, "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(body))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if resp.StatusCode != 201 { // created response code
        bodyBytes, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        return fmt.Errorf("%s", bodyBytes)
    }
    return nil
}
```

And then you can pass in your mock